# ImagingCore Python Object

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I am performing a memory useage analysis of my Python program using the Python Memory Validator. It appears that a lot of 'ImagingCore' objects are being created and are being held in the program's memory. I just want to check: what exactly are these objects? Are they PIL image instances? Other photo related objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the [ImagingCore objects underly the presented Image API](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-image-sig/205/) in PIL.